# JUNG nested nodes

Tags: java, graph, visualization, jung

I'm wondering if it's possible/how I would go about creating something like this in JUNG:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "something like this".  If you want a single nice, neat diagram of a fixed graph, then you're probably better off drawing it by hand.

If you want a more general solution (data model and visualization) for graphs whose nodes can also be graphs, check out the tree node collapse and vertex collapse demos here:

http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/index.html